# how to delete array inside array by value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

suppose, I have array  `let arr = [0,1,[2],3,4]`

i want to remove [2] from `arr` array by only value [2].

expected array would be `arr = [0,1,3,4]`

i appreciate your help,
thank you.

Comment: You can do like this `arr.filter(x=>typeof(x)!="object")`

Comment: @SourabhSomani I guess the OP doesn't want to simply remove all objects

Answer (score 0):

This should help!

```js
let arr = [0, 1, [2], 3, 4, 'A', [2], { name: 'John' }];

const match = (a1, a2) => {
  if (a1.length !== a2.length) return false;
  for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    if (a1[i] !== a2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
};

const target = [2];
arr = arr.filter((el) => !match(el, target));

console.log(arr);
```